# What is the Ubuntu "tang" process

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

My Ubuntu 12.04 server is becoming periodically non-responsive.  Upon recovery (while I'm running top) I see a bunch of processes named "tang".  They aren't using a ton of resources (around 3% cpu), but I have no idea what they are or what they are doing.  My Google-fu is failing me on this one.  Does anyone have any idea what that process is?

Thank you in advance!

Follow Up: After additional digging the server was indeed breached. It turns out there was a collection of binaries copied and running from the /root/ and /home/ directories.

There is a list below of the various binaries in case it helps anyone coming after me. I was able to quickly disable the network interfaces on the server, copy known and needed files off and then fire up a new server.

The logs were clean, so I'm assuming this was a result of not patching the heartbleed bug fast enough on the server. Attack happened April 17th.

Rogue Binaries:
tang
yang
yangji32
yangji64
mash
999
dd.64
trffg
weim3
weimiao32
weimiao64 xiaoweigj
xudp
124.173

Comment: Can you check `ls -l /proc/$PID_OF_PROCESS/exe` and look up the full path to the binary in the repository with `dpkg -S /path/to/bin`?

Comment: The process seems to be transient, the PIDs I had seen in top before are now gone. Doing a search i found tang in /root/tang.  The dpgk result: dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /root/tang.

Comment: Congratulations, your server has been compromised.

Comment: You can do a bit more investigation with `netstat -tapn|grep tang` and `lsof $pid` but treat server as compromised unless proven otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the /root/tang to a different directory to prevent it from being deleted. If it wasn't installed by a package and you didn't install it yourself there is the possibility that your server was compromised.

Run a `strings /dir/where/you/copied/it/to/tang` to find any clues as to what it does (don't run it!). It might be a good precaution to disconnect the server from the network or move it to a VLAN which has no access to internal resources. If you're feeling lucky, run the program with `strace tang`, this should give you some insight in what it does. Make sure you take precautions before doing this like moving the server to a different VLAN and removing any sensitive information. You might also want to sniff the server's network so you can see which resources on the internet it interacts with.

Comment: ok, thanks.  I'm doing some additional investigation.  I'll report back anything else i find to document it here.